# Calculation of RMS between two grids

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster, saga, statistics

I want to calculate the RMSE of two grids based on their z-value: a calculated and a reference grid.
I do have the statistics: Cells, Range, Min, Max, Sum, Mean, Variance, St.dev.

How could I solve the problem using e.g. ArcGIS or SAGA Gis?